# JavaFX BarChart - minimum value for Y Axis

Tags: java, javafx, bar-chart

I have data which changes from 750 000 - 1 000 000+- so I actually dont need to see value under 750 000.

If I just making y[i] - 750 000 so there's another problem (shows on AxisY min 0 and to 250 000+-)

How can i make this with `BarChart`?

```
BarChart<String,Number> bc= new BarChart<String, Number>(xAxis,yAxis);//statistic-years
bc.setTitle("Statistic-Years");
xAxis.setLabel("Country");
yAxis.setLabel("Value");
int[] cityPopulation = {
    857200, 866500,871100,880400,889600,891900, 889800, 882100, 873200, 864400, 854300, 844300, 831500, 818910,
    816382, 814255,813159,811939,812990,812862, 812605, 814224, 814070, 815786, 816061, 815269, 814758, 813387};
int[] countryPopulation = {
        1075400,1059100,1043300,1028000,1022300,1012900,999900,993100,987300,980200,974400,966700,959500,953461,937490,
        921981, 906978, 889632, 873477, 859355, 847370, 836384,827131,818401,810977,802993,795815,788776,
};
XYChart.Series series1 = new XYChart.Series();
series1.setName("Country population");
XYChart.Series series2 = new XYChart.Series();
series2.setName("City population");
bc.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 14;-fx-font-weight: bolder;");
bc.setStyle("CHART_COLOR_1: rgb(2,0,94); " + "CHART_COLOR_2: rgb(189,0,18); ");
for (int i =0;i<cityPopulation.length;i++) {
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(""+(i+1989),countryPopulation[i]));
    series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(""+(i+1989),cityPopulation[i]));
}
bc.getData().add(series1);
bc.getData().add(series2);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The axis has these boundaries because the default value of the  [`autoRangingProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/chart/Axis.html#autoRangingProperty) is `true` and the default value of the [`forceZeroInRangeProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/chart/NumberAxis.html#forceZeroInRangeProperty) is also `true`.

This means, that the axis will set its own boundaries automatically, while keeping the zero value always displayed, therefore the lower bound will be at least zero.

You can set the `forceZeroInRangeProperty` to false which will lead to have automatic ranging, but as the zero value is not forced to be displayed, the boundaries will be calculated based on the minimum and maximum value on the data displayed.

```
yAxis.setForceZeroInRange(false);
```

Alternatively you can manually set the axis boundaries with:

Either using for example the appropiate [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/chart/NumberAxis.html#NumberAxis-double-double-double-) to set the lower and upper bound:

```
NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis(700000, 1200000, 1000);
```

or by setting the `autoRangingProperty` to `false` and the [`lowerBoundProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/chart/ValueAxis.html#lowerBoundProperty) and the [`upperBoundProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/chart/ValueAxis.html#upperBoundProperty--) to the needed values:

```
NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
yAxis.setAutoRanging(false);
yAxis.setLowerBound(700000);
yAxis.setUpperBound(1200000);
```

**Example chart by setting `forceZeroInRangeProperty` to false:**

[image]

Comment: Oh thanks so much

Tried just this one, but it hasnt worked out :/  `yAxis.setLowerBound(700000);`